# Information Retreival From Several Raspberry Pi 3s'

Tags: pi-3, networking

I am implementing a simple project with several Raspberry Pi 3s' connected to my home network. I hosted a web server using PHP on lighttpd server on one pi that I am calling my "central node".

I have a python script on that central node that reads some sensor information through the GPIO pins. Now, what I want to accomplish, is to obtain the sensor data from the other nodes on my network ( the other Pi 3s' apart from the central one ).

I thought about SSH remote execution from the central Pi to the other Pis' to run the script and get back the data. But that would be a problem since my router uses DHCP and the Pis' get assigned different IP Addresses each time. So there isn't a way to differentiate between them as such.
Another way would be to SSH the Pi using their MAC addresses, but it being a Layer 2 protocol, wouldn't be usable outside the same network.

So what should I do in this scenario ? The data feed needs to be realtime to the central node. If necessary, I can host the webserver on a separate machine and use the Pis' only for data retrieval as well.

Comment: Why not create a script that runs on the non-central Pi's that makes a web request to the central Pi's web server and stores the data to the DB?

Comment: That would involve setting up all the other Pi's individually. I was looking for more of a plug and play type of system.
For eg, just hook up the Pi to the network, and the central server would configure all the communications automatically@SteveRobillard

Comment: Can't you use the machine names instead of the IP addresses for the slave Pi's?

Comment: Regarding @Steve Robillard's suggestion, you can still remotely configure the slave devices from the central node.

Comment: That would restrict me to an inter-network operation only. Can't use machine names outside of the network @wasatchwizard

Comment: If I use a public (external) webserver, I can use python to send HTTP requests to it for data submission. But how do I invoke the script on a particular pi from suppose a button click on the hosted website ?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an perfect application for [MQTT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT). You can connect all your devices to a cloud broker , and the devices can publish and subcribe to message feeds. This is different from one-to-one client-server relationships and more powerful.

https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-php.html

If you wish , you can install a private broker on your own Pi inside your home network instead.